# Develop Software for Microchip ARM Controller in MPLABX?

Tags: arm, mplabx

Is it possible to develop and debug software for a microchip ARM controller in MPLABX?

Comment: This isn't as obvious a question as it might seem. At the moment *probably* "no" but the website doesn't really make it all that clear.  There is a downloadable list of supported devices, the AVR parts whose addition to it is currently the news splash are not on that list.  It's not clear that there are any non-ex-Atmel ARM parts offered; for those Atmel studio seems to still be the official choice, or just use the same gcc complier yourself with your existing preference of configurable IDE.  I'd expect they will eventually integrate them. **If you want a definitive answer contact support**.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask that question on the Microchip forum. http://www.microchip.com/forums/f238.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will start a support ticket a microchip and tell you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the answer from microchip:

MPLAB X IDE v5.05 has beta support for 16 SAM devices.
These are the devices that are currently beta supported under MPLAB X
IDE v5.05:

```
ATSAMV71Q21
ATSAMS70Q21B
ATSAMS70Q20B
ATSAMS70N21B
ATSAMS70N20B
ATSAMS70J21B
ATSAMS70J20B
ATSAME70Q21B
ATSAME70Q20B
ATSAME70N21B
ATSAME70N20B
ATSAME70J21B
ATSAME70J20B
ATSAMD21J18A
ATSAMD20J18
ATSAMC21N18A
```

Please continue using Atmel Studio for SAM Devices, till MPLAB X doesn't
fully support the ARM devices.
More details about the Atmel Studio ecosystem can be found here:
http://www.microchip.com/mplab/avr-support

Update:
[Here](https://packs.download.microchip.com/DeviceDoc/Device_Support.pdf) is a list of the supported devices with tne newer MPLABX versions.

Comment: Thanks for returning to update your question with your findings.  Please come back again after the self-answer lockout expires and accept your answer so that it shows as resolved.